# Factorial of a large number in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am a beginner in c++. I was solving problems in CodeChef and came across this prooblem: http://www.codechef.com/problems/FCTRL2

The problem asks you to find the factorial of large numbers. To achieve this I am trying to perform digit by digit multiplication. However, in my code in line 39 the sum of "b[i] * c[j] * pow(10,(i+j)) + x" is being reduced by 1 from 3rd iteration of the loop. I am not able to figure out the reason for sum being reduced by 1.

Kingly help me out with this problem.

Here is the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <cmath>

    using namespace std;

    // to find the number of digits
    int num_digits(int val) {
        int digits = 0;
        while(val) {
            val /= 10;
            digits++;
        }
        return digits;
    }

    int main() {
       std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
       int b[10], c[10], num1, num2, x=0, num_inputs;
       std::cin >> num_inputs;
       while(num_inputs) {
            std::cin >> num1;
            num2 = num1 - 1;

            int num1_digits = num_digits(num1);
            int num2_digits = num_digits(num2);

            int temp1 = num1;
            int temp2 = num2;

            while(num2>0) {
                std::cout << temp2 << " " << temp1 << " " << num1_digits << " " << num2_digits<< endl;
                for(int i=0; i<num2_digits; i++) {
                    b[i] = temp2 % 10;
                    temp2 /= 10;
                        for(int j=0; j<num1_digits; j++) {
                            c[j] = temp1 % 10;
                            temp1 /= 10;
                            std::cout << b[i] << " " << c[j] << " " << pow(10, (i+j)) << " ";
                            x = b[i] * c[j] * pow(10,(i+j)) + x; // the sum is getting reduced by 1
                            std::cout << x << endl;
                        }
                    temp1 = num1;
                }
                num2--;
                temp2 = num2;
                temp1 = x;
                x = 0;
                num1_digits = num_digits(temp1);
                num2_digits = num_digits(temp2);

            }
            std::cout << temp1;
            num_inputs--;
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand the point of even having `temp1`, `temp2`, and `x`, rather than just working with the digits like you say you want to.

Comment: Here's a tutorial for this question [Computing Factorials of a huge number in C/C++: A tutorial](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/7349/computing-factorials-of-a-huge-number-in-cc-a-tutorial) on codechef.

Answer (score 0):

`pow` is floating-point exponentiation, not integer exponentiation. You should only use it when you want approximate, floating point results, not exact, integer results.